# How to update Java from 8 Update 31 to 8 Update 51 when install fails?

Tags: macos, install, software-update, java

I'm trying to update Java on my Mac OSX Yosemite.  In the `Java Control Panel`, it states:

```
A critical Java security update is available.

8 Update 51 (57 MB)

Your current version is Java 8 Update 31. It is recommended that you update 
now to keep your system secure.
```

I click the `Update Now` button and it brings up the `Software Update` dialog that indicates I must relaunch the browser to update, but it will not need to reboot the computer.  I click the `Install Update` button which brings up the `Updating Java` dialog that downloads 60 MB, extracts it, and then very briefly says `ready to update` before disappearing.  Returning to the `Java Control Panel` shows I'm still on `Update 31`, repeating the process has same result.

How can I get the update to actually install?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the installed version and manually download the current release and then install it?

Comment: No need to uninstall the current version. Just download the update 51 and install. Check version in Terminal or Java panel. It will show the updated version.

Comment: @PratikaRana I see the same issue - The Update doesn't seem to have any effect.  Repeating the Update still has no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to uninstall the current version. From the Java website just download the Java 8 update 51 (JDK)from Oracle site and install manually. After installation, no need to reboot the machine. Check version in Terminal or Java panel. It will show the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

When an automated update process fails without an explicit reason then one method of dealing with it is to manually uninstalled the present installed version and then install the current full version downloaded manually from the source website.

Looking at [How do I uninstall Java on my Mac?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml), which applies to versions 7.0, 8.0 on OS X for the **JRE**, one needs to do the following:

> **Uninstall Oracle Java using the Terminal**
>
> **Note:** To uninstall Java, you must have Administrator privileges and execute the remove command either as root or by using the sudo.
>   Remove one directory and one file (a symlink), as follows:
>
> 1. Click on the **Finder** icon located in your dock
> 2. Click on the **Utilities** folder
> 3. Double-click on the **Terminal** icon
> 4. In the Terminal window **Copy and Paste** the command below:
>
>    `sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`
>
>    `sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefpane`
>
> Do not attempt to uninstall Java by removing the Java tools from
>   `/usr/bin`. This directory is part of the system software and any
>   changes will be reset by Apple the next time you perform an update of
>   the OS.

**Manually download the latest version from:** [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

**Note:**  For normal **Browser** usage choose the **JRE** however if wanting to use the latest Java from the Command Line in a Terminal choose the **JDK**.  Additionally if you already have the Java JDK installed I noticed that after updating from version 1.8.0_45 to 1.8.0_51 via the **Java Control Panel** under **System Preferences** that it only updated the **JRE** components to version1.8.0_51, not the **JDK** and it remained at 1.8.0_45.

So I uninstalled the **JDK** following the directions in [Uninstalling the JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#uninstall) as well as the commands from the directions listed above.

> **Uninstalling the JDK** To uninstall the JDK, you must have Administrator privileges and execute the remove command either as root
>   or by using the sudo(8) tool.
>
> Navigate to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and remove the
>   directory whose name matches the following format:*
>
> ```
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<major>.<minor>.<macro[_update]>.jdk
> ```
>
> For example, to uninstall 7u6:
>
> ```
> % rm -rf jdk1.7.0_06.jdk
> ```
>
> Do not attempt to uninstall Java by removing the Java tools from
>   `/usr/bin`. This directory is part of the system software and any
>   changes will be reset by Apple the next time you perform an update of
>   the OS
>   *The 7u4 and 7u5 releases were installed into a directory that does not follow this format. To uninstall 7u4 or 7u5, remove the 1.7.0.jdk
>   directory from the same location.

I then downloaded the current JDK and installed it and am now using the latest version of Java both in a Browser and the Command Line in a Terminal.